# System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name' + _ViewStart.cshtml + Razor + C#.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, argumentnullexception

## Error in _ViewStart.cshtml with DotRez Razor

### Steps

I'm trying debug my app (with IIS Express or IIS) but appear error of ArgumentNullException, but if I open de app only with IIS without attach the app, it open correctly.

### Exception

System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Arg_ParamName_Name'

[image]

I want to debug my app and I don't have any idea of what is the problem.
I have Windows 10 and run with Visual Studio 2022 Professional

Comment: Hi @Alejandrop, could you pls share your whole code in  _ViewStart.cshtml?

Comment: Please don't post images. I for one can't read the text that is highlighted within the image. There's also possible code hidden behind the exception message box. Please post the section of code that triggers the exception and the exception text. At a guess I'd say that you're adding a `KeyValuePair<string, string>` without initialising the string values.